# Send hashed or encrypted password to AS400 jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, ibm-midrange

Need to send a hashed or encrypted password when creating the db connection, see details below:

We have a Spring application that connects to a DB2 AS400 database. We are currently using configuration files (.properties) to store the connection details, Spring reads thes files in the context creation phase and creates the datasource accordingly.

```
...
database.driverClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
database.url=jdbc:as400:<host>:naming=sql;libraries=*LIBL,...;transaction isolation=none

database.username=<user>
database.password=<password>

database.initialPoolSize=2
database.maxPoolSize=5
...
```

This .properties file lives in the application/web server's file sytem.

I have a requirement to store a hashed password instead of the password directly, that way if someone looks at the file content cannot know what the real password is.

Like this using SHA:

```
...
database.password=5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
...
```

There must be a way for telling AS400 that the password being sent is hashed.

In my research I found that AS400 stores passwords using an index QSYUPTBL in the library QSYS, which is able to use DES or SHA hashing algorithms. So it will encrypt the received password and will compare the resulting hash with the one stored in the index. But is it possible to tell the DB's authentication process to expect the password being hashed and compare it directly?

**New finding:**

The documentation from IBM mentions one keyword:  RMTAUTMTH for setting the remote authentication method, using the *ENCRYPTED value in that param will activate the encryption in user id and password:

...User ID and associated encrypted password is sent on a DDM connection request. Cryptographic support must be available on both systems for this authentication method to be used... extracted from http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/cl/chgrdbdire.htm

So it seems that it can be configured in the AS400 side, but does not mention anything about the encryption algorithm being used and if the jdbc driver supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention of a property in the [IBM Toolbox for Java JDBC properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm) to accept a special hashed/encrypted password.

You are going to have to manage the hashing/encryption of the password within your application and provide it to the JDBC connection as plaintext.

The `secure` property of the JDBC connection can be used to force an SSL connection to the AS/400, assuming SSL is enabled, to ensure that all data is encrypted between the application and the database.